# How to get access to Vuex store of parent Vue app from iframed child app?

Tags: vue.js, iframe, micro-frontend

I'm coding a main web app (with VueJS & VueCLI, as SPA) with only some foundation features. I aim at providing a platform where other developers could independently build add-ons by coding & deploying their own web app (with any framework) at it's specific domain, then the main web app have a page to load the add-on URL in iframe tag.

It's sound like micro-frontends architecture. And here's what missing: if the main web app handles login process and keeps user account object in Vuex, then how coud I efficiently get access to Vuex of the main web app from the add-ons web app?

If iframe it not a suitable solution, so what's the best strategy for me?

I open to discussion & really appreciate any help!

Comment: Is the iframe hosted on the same domain as the parent?

Comment: Each add-on is deployed by it's owner and it may have separate domain. E.g: the main app's URL: mainapp.com, the calendar add-on's URL: my-calendar.com, ...etc. But what is the different in case the iframe and the main web app are on the same domain?